# How to add new managed object from other app?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have used Core Data just creating projects with "Use Core Data" checked, using the code that XCode creates by default and, if necessary, adding or modifying just a few things.

Now I have a "main" app and I have created a helper app (status bar item app, LSUIElement = 1 and Login item). The helper app is Build as main app target dependency and copied into the main app "Resources" folder.

When the status bar icon is clicked the helper app shows a window to the user to collect some info to create a new managed object according to the main app Core Data Model.

But, how can I create a new managed object from the helper app for the main app?

By now I´m thinking to:

- check if main app is open or not (I don´t know if it´s possible)
- if it´s open, let the main app to perfom a selector with a dictionary with the info sent from helper app (I don´t know if it´s possible)
- if it´s close then (in the helper app) create a persistent store coordinator, manage object model and manage object context using the model and persistent store files from main app. Create the new managed object. And I don´t know if it´s better to terminate MOC, MOM and PSC each time the user creates a new MO to avoid conflicts when main app opens or it´s not optimal and could affect performance...

It´s a good approach? Any point to start? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to create a managed object? If you're just collecting simple data in the helper app it would be much simpler to pass that input to the main app via the userinfo dictionary in  a Distributed Notification. Then the main app could create the managed object and you don't have to deal with merging changes between the two contexts.

Otherwise you'd have to pass the helper app a path to your MOM, create a MOC in the helper app, create the object, save the MOC while notifying the main app to merge changes by passing the IDs of the changed objects, reloading your main app's model objects, and so on. I've gotten it to work, but it's a huge headache and prone to errors. I'd avoid that route if possible.

Edit: I just realized you want to be able to write to your main app's store even if it's not running. It sounds like you need to re-think this before writing any code. If the helper app executes on its own, it's not really a helper app. Could you go into more detail about what you're actually trying to accomplish? This kind of hackery is not really a good idea and could lead to data corruption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Francis! I continued searching more info about this and thinking how to solve it. And I'm completely agree with you: it´s not necessary to create the MO in the helper app. I've been testing  the distributed notifications and works perfect. I'm using -[NSWorkspace launchedApplications] to check if the main app is open. If main app is closed (I haven´t tested this yet) the helper can use a plist to store the info and main app can check it (for pending MO to create) at launch ... what do you think?

Comment: Tested and finished. Everything works fine. Thanks again Francis!